# Regexp with global flag only matching first match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

Why does:

```
/(\[#([0-9]{8})\])/g.exec("[#12345678] [#87654321] [#56233001] [#36381069] [#23416459] [#56435355]")
```

return

> ["[#12345678]", "[#12345678]", "12345678"]

I want it to match all those numbers but it appears to be too greedy.

> [#12345678] [#87654321] [#56233001] [#36381069] [#23416459] [#56435355] 12345678 87654321 56233001 36381069 23416459 56435355

Comment: It ain't greedy. `exec` is just displaying the first match but returns an array. Hence loop through the array of matches and drop the outer capturing parentheses .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how `.exec()` works. To get multiple results, run it in a loop.

```
var re = /(\[#([0-9]{8})\])/g,
    str = "[#12345678] [#87654321] [#56233001] [#36381069] [#23416459] [#56435355]",
    match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

Also, the outer capture group seems extraneous. You should probably get rid of that.

```
/\[#([0-9]{8})\]/g,
```

Result:

```
[
    "[#12345678]",
    "12345678"
],
[
    "[#87654321]",
    "87654321"
],
[
    "[#56233001]",
    "56233001"
],
[
    "[#36381069]",
    "36381069"
],
[
    "[#23416459]",
    "23416459"
],
[
    "[#56435355]",
    "56435355"
]
```

Comment: +1. See documentation at [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Answer (score 1):

`regex.exec` returns the groups in your regex (the things wrapped in parenthesis).

The function you're looking for is one you call on the string, `match`.

`string.match(regex)` returns all of the matches.

```
"[#12345678] [#87654321] [#56233001] [#36381069] [#23416459] [#56435355]".match(/(\[#([0-9]{8})\])/g)
// yields: ["[#12345678]", "[#87654321]", "[#56233001]", "[#36381069]", "[#23416459]", "[#56435355]"]
```

EDIT:

If you just want the numbers without the brackets and the #, just change the regex to `/\d{8}/g`

```
"[#12345678] [#87654321] [#56233001] [#36381069] [#23416459] [#56435355]".match(/[0-9]{8}/g)
// yields: ["12345678", "87654321", "56233001", "36381069", "23416459", "56435355"]
```

Comment: Only problem is that you lose the capture group when you use `.match`.

Comment: It's not clear what OP's end goal is. In this scenario, who needs the capture groups? You know there was a leading `[#` and trailing `]` surrounding the numbers.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty likely that the grouped digits is the target. Your updated regex will work, given the assumption that there can be no other digit sets that could cause a false positive. From the given example, I'd call it safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` method of a string to collect all the matches:

```
var s = "[#12345678] [#87654321] [#56233001] [#36381069] [#23416459] [#56435355]";
var re = /\[#([0-9]{8})\]/g;
var l = [];
s.replace(re, function($0, $1) {l.push($1)});
// l == ["12345678", "87654321", "56233001", "36381069", "23416459", "56435355"]
```

Comment: Using replace is not necessary here when we have a `match`

Comment: @Kash: If capture groups are going to be used, then you'd need `.replace()` to access the group value *(assuming a String method instead of a RegExp method)*.

Comment: The group value is already in the 2-dim array, so what are we replacing?

Comment: @Kash: Using `.match`, the result is `["[#12345678]", "[#87654321]", "[#56233001]", ...]` The desired result is `["12345678", "87654321", "56233001", ...]`. There's nothing being replaced, but using `.replace()` gives you access to the sub-group, so it can be pushed into the result Array. Using `.match()`, you lose the sub-group, so you'd need to loop the result and remove the unwanted characters.

Comment: The actual value captured by the parentheses is still available in the array. Check my answer.

Comment: @Kash: Your answer doesn't use `String#match`. It uses `RegExp#exec`

Comment: @graystateiscoming - Ah! Now I understand the miscommunication. LOL. I was referring to using `exec` as OP was doing before. Didn't realize your preference of using String.

Comment: @Kash: Oh, I see. Since the word "match" had code highlighting in your first comment, I assumed you were referring to the `String#match` method. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var re = /\[#(\d{8})\]/g;
    var sourcestring = "[#12345678] [#87654321] [#56233001] [#36381069] [#23416459] [#56435355]";
    var results = [];
    var i = 0;
    var matches;
    while (matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
        results[i] = matches;
        alert(results[i][1]);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES2020 there is a new feature added [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) witch does the job.